# Qt - How detect possible invalid data loss with QTextStream readAll?

Tags: qt, utf-8

I am reading in a file that *should* be UTF-8 encoded using `QTextStream::readAll()`. If I attempt to open a corrupt UTF-8 file (or a binary file) I want to know that the data was not valid UTF-8.

I tried checking the `status()` after the read, but it did not indicate any abnormal condition.

I know I could read the whole file in binary mode and write a routine to check it myself, but it seems there should be an easier way, since the read has done all that UTF-8 conversion already.

Answer (score 0):

You can use QTextCodec for this.

```
QTextCodec * QTextCodec::codecForUtfText(const QByteArray & ba, QTextCodec * defaultCodec)
```

From documentation:

> Tries to detect the encoding of the provided snippet ba by using the
>   BOM (Byte Order Mark) and returns a QTextCodec instance that is
>   capable of decoding the text to unicode. If the codec cannot be
>   detected from the content provided, defaultCodec is returned.

Comment: Does this actually check the entire file? I need to know if the entire file is valid UTF-8 or not.